# I want to make instance with array in SystemC

Tags: c++, systemc

I want to make instance with array in SystemC.

I want to write as follows:

```
module name = new module[10];
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    module name[i]("any names")
}
```

However, I did this, the compiler said:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'module::module()'
```

Please tell me how to make an instance with array.

Comment: you are missing constructor function of your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SystemC, you can use `sc_vector` instead of a plain C array, see e.g.

- https://standards.ieee.org/standard/1666-2011.html (Section 8.5)
- https://complex.offis.de/documents/doc_details/29-scvector-and-the-ieee-p1666-2011-systemc-standard.html

```cpp
SC_MODULE(top)
{
  sc_vector<module> m; // e.g. class member

  SC_CTOR(top)
    : m("modules", 10) // constructor
  {}
};
```